# Foreign key cannot be created id MySQL: missing index on column(s)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a few foreign keys set up, however phpMyAdmin would not let me to create one more. Here are table in question:

```
Groups Table

id
name
address


Tasks Table

id
group_id
name
```

I need a foreign key on `group_id` in `Tasks Table`, but when I try to create in it provides the following error: `Missing index on column(s)`. If I add a unique constrain on `group_id` I am then able to create the foreign key, but the ralation then becomes `One to One`, which is not the expected result.

Following are table create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `groups`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `fixed_tasks`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Show the table create statment and the create Statement for the foreign key

Comment: So create a non-unique index instead?

Comment: I have just updated the question with table create statements. I always use designer view in phpMyAdmin to create relations, so I do not have a statement for foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code can create two tables with relative foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `Groups` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `Tasks` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `group_id` INT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `Groups` (`id`)
);
```